# How do I install GULP for a project

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am trying to install GULP but can not get it to install the files in a local directory. I have successfully installed Node.js and opened the NodeJS Command Promt. Next I entered the below line to install GULP on my machine. It fetched a load of files so did run succesfully.

```
npm install --global gulp
```

Then I created a folder on my desktop to which I created a new packages.js file in here to. Next I navigated to this folder with my NodeJS Command Prompt by entering the following;

```
cd {Then the path to my folder]
```

Next I enter

```
$ npm install gulp --save-dev
```

This then fetches a load of files (GET etc) but when I look in my folder I have nothing? There's no node_modules folder and an npm-debug.log file or anything? Any help welcome.

Comment: Have you read this? https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Comment: If it showed a successful install, then there should be a node_modules folder. Maybe you look at the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. When I follow this I get $ isn't recognised and nothing happens anyway :)

Comment: dont write $ it show you that this is a command

Comment: What evidence is there that it is not installed?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **npm install --save-dev gulp** (from one tutorial) or **npm install --save-dev gulp-install** (from another tutorial), none of which created any gulp related files in my project folder, I used **npm install gulp** and it worked.

Comment: This also needs to run npm init after installing globally, then after the init, install it into a project with npm install gulp --save-dev